# Android APP to login a site. Why this won't work?

Tags: android, http, post, android-intent, request

I'm making a POST request with login/pass and opening the site with an Intent. The site is opening but it is not logged in. What is wrong?

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite.co/login.php");

    try {

        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", "mypass"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "myuser"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://mysite.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Http is stateless. The server has no way of knowing that you were the same app that logged in a couple seconds ago as you are now that you're opening the intent. I don't think that the cookies (if that is the authentication method used on the site) are being passed to the intent, so as far as the server knows you're a brand new connection.

Comment: I give down vote by mistake. here are any option to remove it. I am very sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that you are login into a website in your application. So, all cookies (which shows whether you are logged in or not) are stored in response.

You send new intent, which open a browser. However, browser doesn't have access to these cookies which are saved in your response. So when it tries to access website, the website doesn't get a cookie and thinks that you aren't logged it.

I would say you should remove whole first part of this code and just have something like this:

```
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://mysite.com/login.php?user=myuser&pass=mypass"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

This way the broswer will send authentication information and will receive a cookie in response and use it for any following communications.

Comment: But is not this a different type of request? "Get", I guess?

Comment: Yes. You are right. It's different type of request. And there are problems with GET (as example that your user will see username and pass in URL). Also, you server side should handle this correctly. However, I think it will be only method to login through browser. Another idea would be to use WebView (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting that when you open the Browser, you will be logged in, IMO that is not possible.

This is because `httpclient` that does the login request are not shared between your app and the Browser app, so there is no way to pass the cookies that you have recieved when you logged in.